# STM32 Artificial Intelligence

Tags: c, artificial-intelligence, stm32

I'm working on STM32l476g-DISCO and I want to try the Artifical intelligence feature using STM32 CUBEMX but I couldn't see the output (prediction/decision) neither understand the validation (validation on desktop and validation on target)

I was following the ST Microelectronics Demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szMGedsp9jc&t=314s

Can someone please explain the results of the output of the validation on desktop and the validation on the target, and how can I see the decision output?

If I enter a custom data of someone 'sitting' for example how can I see if my model is working perfectly on the STM32?

Comment: *Artifical intelligence feature* of what?

Comment: He means STM ML library

Comment: Runing a Keras or Caffe Pre-trained model on STM32 and seeing the results

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking two questions. 
1) For the validation, I think that it basically means that it shows how different are the results in the original NN (done in python and with Keras) and the results in the converted C++ network (implemented in your desktop and in the microprocessor)

2) If you want to see the network in action and predicting something I recommend the following example:

[Hand written digits recognition on STM32F4](https://github.com/nimaaghli/STM32AI_MNIST)

In the code you can see the original NN in python and then the implementation of it in C to be used to recognize digits.

Take special attention to the function `MX_X_CUBE_AI_Process(in_data,out_data,1);` which is where the prediction occurs.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what kansaiTobot has said,
from CubeMX-AI you have three modes of operation

1- Validation ==> compare the result of model implemented in Python against the C/C++ model , this mode has two options you can do validaion of C/C++ on Host PC and you can do it on target micro-Controller

2- System Performance  ==> measure the required CPU load and memory usage for the NN

3- Application template  ==>  here you can supply your input data and get the result from the neural network

you can find more information in the user manual AI on STM32 
"Getting started with X-CUBE-AI Expansion Package for Artificial Intelligence (AI)"